# Will sounds embedded in a python script play on another computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am curious to know if I send someone a python file with embedded sound files, if it will still play on another computer or if the file has to be in their drive.

Here I am using playsound, but I can use other modules as needed.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('partyhorn.wav')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. The file has to be in the same relative directory.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will just send a zip file containing the sound files